# Função recursiva com for

Tags: javascript, recursão

Estou estudando funções recursivas e me surgiu uma dúvida quando eu estava olhando alguns algoritmos que usam função recursiva e `for`. 
Resolvi então criar um exemplo simples e imprimir alguns valores na tela para tentar entender como fica o fluxo do programa e acabei me enrolando mais ainda.

Alguém poderia me explicar o que acontece?

Desculpem se não estou sendo claro o suficiente, sou iniciante e não sei me expressar muito bem.

Segue o código:

```
function x(n){
    console.log('before , n: ',n);
    if(n === 0)return;
    for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++){  
        console.log('for i:',i);  
        x(n-1);
    }
    console.log('after, n: ',n);
}
x(3);
```

**Segue o print:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chamamos de recursividade ou recursão quando uma função chama a si mesma.

Em uma função recursiva, a cada chamada é criada na memória uma **nova ocorrência** da função com comandos e variáveis "isolados" das ocorrências anteriores, por tanto um novo escopo para cada chamada a função.

No momento que é executado a linha `x(n-1)`, a ocorrência atual aguarda uma resposta da nova ocorrência, ou seja, é preciso esperar o resultado da operação `x(n-1)` para que a operação seguinte seja executada.

Na prática ocorre as seguintes operações:

1. Chamada a função `x(n)`.
2. Imprime na console o valor de `n` (before).
3. Termina a ocorrência se `n` for igual a `0` retonando uma resposta a ocorrência anterior (se existir).
4. Ciclo `for`.
5. Imprime na console o valor de `i`.
6. Inicia uma nova ocorrência `x(n-1)` (volta ao ponto 2) e aguarda pela resposta.
7. Volta ao ponto `4` se `i < 3`.
8. Imprime na consola o valor de `n` (after).

Veja que no ponto `6` criamos uma nova ocorrência (n-1) e isso faz com que a ocorrencia atual (n) aguarde a resposta da nova ocorrência antes de passar para o ponto `7`.

Um exemplo passo a passo para `n=2` de acordo com o esquema acima:

```
1. x(2);
2. print "before, n: 2"
3. N > 0
4. For i=1
5. print "for i: 1"
6. x(1) //n-1 em que n=2
    1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
    2. print "before, n: 1"
    3. N > 0
    4. For i=1
    5. print "for i: 1"
    6. x(0) //n-1 em que n=1
        1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
        2. print "before, n: 0"
        3. N <= 0
        8. print "after, n: 0"
        [Termina a ocorrência]
    4. For i=2
    5. print "for i: 2"
    6. x(0) //n-1 em que n=1
        1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
        2. print "before, n: 0"
        3. N <= 0
        8. print "after, n: 0"
        [Termina a ocorrência]
    4. For i=3
    8. print "after, n: 1"
    [Termina a ocorrência]
4. For i=2
5. print "for i: 2"
6. x(1) //n-1 em que n=2
    1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
    2. print "before, n: 1"
    3. N > 0
    4. For i=1
    5. print "for i: 1"
    6. x(0) //n-1 em que n=1
        1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
        2. print "before, n: 0"
        3. N <= 0
        8. print "after, n: 0"
        [Termina a ocorrência]
    4. For i=2
    5. print "for i: 2"
    6. x(0) //n-1 em que n=1
        1. Iniciou uma nova ocorrência
        2. print "before, n: 0"
        3. N <= 0
        8. print "after, n: 0"
        [Termina a ocorrência]
    4. For i=3
    8. print "after, n: 1"
    [Termina a ocorrência]
4. For i=3
8. print "after, n: 2"
[Termina a ocorrência]
```

Na listagem acima, usei os espaços na horizontal para simular uma nova ocorrência da função `x`.

Se extrairmos apenas as linhas em que aparece o "print", teremos o seguinte:

```
before, n: 2
for i: 1
   before, n: 1 
   for i: 1
      before, n: 0
      after, n: 0
   for i: 2
      before, n: 0
      after, n: 0
   after, n: 1
for i: 2
   before, n: 1
   for i: 1
      before, n: 0
      after, n: 0
   for i: 2
      before, n: 0
      after, n: 0
    after, n: 1
after, n: 2
```

Apesar da primeira ocorrência ser `x(2)`, o `after, n: 2` só aparece no fim da lista porque novas ocorrências surgiram pelo meio e dispararam o `console.log` antes de devolver uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

A sua duvida é "por que o `for` está salvando o valor de `i = 2` depois do base case ser atingido?"

Isto é porque o javascript tem `function scope` ao invés de `block scope`, sendo que a inicialização de `i` é feita dentro da função onde o `for` está, então ele conhece o valor.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre esses termos para aprender mais. Em relação ao fluxo do código eu tenho outra dúvida, por que depois do `after, n:1`, marcado como azul no print, ele vai direto para o `for` ao invés de ir para o `before, n:1`?

Answer (score -2):

O que ele tá a fazer é: para cada `n`, ele executa esse ciclo 3 vezes. Experimenta mudar o ciclo `for` para `for (var = i ; i < n ; i++)`

Comment: Outra dúvida. Pelo que li, uma função recursiva é executada "n" vezes até chegar no base case e depois retorna "n" resultados montando o resultado final.
Existe termos técnicos para eu me referir quando uma função recursiva está "entrando" e quando ela está "retornando" ?

Comment: PPim, mesmo usando `i<n` a minha dúvida persiste. Olhe a saída:

`
before , n:  3
for i: 1
before , n:  2
for i: 1
before , n:  1
after, n:  1
after, n:  2
for i: 2 
`
por que o `for` está salvando o valor de i = 2 depois do base case ser atingido?